# Jquery function to slide a div on href click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that stretches 400% of the screen. When I click a href I want the div to slide to the left. When So far the div moves to the left then jumps back to its original position. Why is it doing this?

Here is my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#about').click(function() {
        $('#main_div_wide_wrapper').animate({
        'left' : "-=100%" //moves left
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Here is the Html

```
<div id="main_div_wrapper">
    <div id="main_div_wide_wrapper">

    </div><!--end main_div_wide_wrapper-->
</div><!--end main_div_wrapper-->
<a class="bottom_link" href="" id="about">About</a>
```

Here is the Css

```
#main_div_wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:550px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#main_div_wide_wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:400%;
    height:550px;
    background:#000;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Its on a wampserver so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#about').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
        $('#main_div_wide_wrapper').animate({
        'left' : '-=100%' //moves left
        });
    });
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/ft9sJ/1/**

You should use http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ preventDefault() method... I guess that click on link refresh page, so, it is causing 'jump'...

Answer (score 0):

i would try removing the $(document).ready(function() from around it, not necessary if you want it to happen on click. Also i would do it with a margin-left property instead of simply left, when i did sliders, that usually worked out better across the browsers.